# Is it possible to know the texture orientation in the SketchUp Ruby API?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have written some plugins for sketch-up. I want to know if it is possible to know the texture orientation (either vertical or horizontal) programmatically in Ruby.

I used this `face.getUVHelper` to extract the position of the texture on the face, which gives U and V points. What exactly do these U and V points represent? And how can i use them in my code to get the position?

The code is given below:

```
face = Sketchup.active_model.selection[0];

tw = Sketchup.create_texture_writer

uv_helper = face.get_UVHelper true, true, tw

face.outer_loop.vertices.each do |vert|

  uvq = uv_helper.get_back_UVQ(vert.position)

  puts "u=" + uvq.x.to_s + " v=" + uvq.y.to_s

end;
```

Comment: Can you include the code that's giving you trouble?

Comment: U and V are common notation for texture mapping. You can find lots of resources to the general concept of this. As for "orientation" - are you assuming some basic shape of the face, like a square? And relative to a specific world orientation? Texture orientation is very relative and ambiguous - you need to define it in reference to something.